# find row number by group in SQL server table with duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to count the row number by group in a table with some duplications.

Table:

```
id va1ue1 value2  
1   3974   39
1   3974   39
1   972    5
1   972    10
```

SQL:

```
 select id, value1, value2, COUNT(*) cnt
 FROM table
 group by id, value1, value2
 having COUNT(*)  > 1
```

The code only count the duplicated rows.
I need:

```
 id, value1, value2
 1   972      5      
 1   972      10
```

I do not need to count the duplicated rows, I only need the rows that value1 has more than one distinct values in value2 column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
select id, value1, count(distinct value2) cnt
from table
group by id, value1
having count(distinct value2)  > 1
```

If you want detais then:

```
select * from table t1
cross apply(select cnt from(
                            select count(distinct value2) cnt
                            from table t2 
                            where t1.id = t2.id and t1.value1 = t2.value1) t 
            where cnt > 1)ca
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use a trick to count distinct values using window functions.  You might find this a nice solution:

```
select t.id, t.value1, t.value2
from (select t.*, sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by value1) as numvals
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by value1, value2 order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where numvals > 1;
```

Comment: In which version was `COUNT(DISTINCT) OVER` fixed?

Comment: @AndriyM . . . Oops, I was thinking of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way without a `GROUP BY`:

```
 select id, value1, value2
 FROM table AS T1
 where 1 < (
   select  COUNT(*) 
   FROM table AS T2
   where T1.value1 = T2.value1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        value1 ,
                        value2 ,
                        COUNT(*) cnt
               FROM     table
               GROUP BY id ,
                        value1 ,
                        value2
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table1
    WHERE   value1 IN ( SELECT  value1
                        FROM    CTE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `NOT` after `HAVING`, which precisely gets you the rows which are NOT duplicated.

```
 select id, value1, value2
 FROM [table]
 group by id, value1, value2
 having NOT COUNT(*)  > 1
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bf7d/7).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual rows from the table, not just the qualifying `id, value1` pairs, you could do this:

```
WITH discrepancies AS (
  SELECT,
    id,
    value1,
    value2,
    distinctcount = COUNT(DISTINCT value2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value1)
  FROM
    dbo.atable
)
SELECT
  id,
  value1,
  value2
FROM
  discrepancies
WHERE
  distinctcount > 1
;
```

*if* SQL Server 2008 supported `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` with an [OVER clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Basically, it would be the same idea as [Giorgi Nakeuri's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313697/297408), more or less, except you would not be hitting the table more than once.

Alas, there is [no support for `COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER ...` in SQL Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/254393/over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause-for-aggregate-functions) so far. Still, you can use a different method, which will still allow you to touch the table just once and return detail rows nevertheless:

```
WITH discrepancies AS (
  SELECT,
    id,
    value1,
    value2,
    minvalue2 = MIN(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value1),
    maxvalue2 = MAX(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, value1)
  FROM
    dbo.atable
)
SELECT
  id,
  value1,
  value2
FROM
  discrepancies
WHERE
  minvalue2 <> maxvalue2
;
```

The idea here is to get `MIN(value2)` and `MAX(value2)` per each `id, value1` and to see if those differ. If they do, that means you have a discrepancy in this `id, value1` subset and you want that row to be returned.

The method takes advantage of aggregates with an OVER clause to avoid a self-join, and that is precisely the reason why the table is accessed just once here.